# Circuit exercise with diodes

Tags: circuit-analysis, diodes

So , I found this exercise online :

[image]

I am having having a hard time finding the conducting values of the diodes . Will D1 conduct for Vin>=10 and D2 for Vin<=-10? And what will be the value of Vout when both of the diodes don't conduct? (Assume that both of the diodes are ideal ,V2=Vin and V=Vout)

Comment: Edit your question to show what you think will happen if D2 is omitted and then again if D1 is omitted. We'll guide you through it.

Comment: For a diode, note that I have seen "ideal" have two different meanings. Either zero voltage drop or a fixed non-zero drop, usually 0.7V. Your textbook should tell you which they are assuming.

Comment: We get these questions all the time. For example, [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/286414/38098) is a quite similar question. (I've even seen the exact one you posted, I believe.) Have you searched the site here, yet?

Comment: @jonk I did search the site but since i ve reached some post which were uploaded almost 2 years ago i stopped .So, i image-searched the excersice through google and  didnt find something correlated here .My bad,cause as you showed me, a similar question ve already been asked

Comment: @ripmsn No problem. I just wanted to let you know that this question comes up a lot. And, often enough, it's not slightly different but instead quite identical. So I'm sure it is all coming from the same book (Sedra and Smith?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't solve these kinds of problems with a simple equation because the diodes are non-linear.

You need to consider (analyze) four separate cases: both diodes conducting, neither diode conducting, only D1 conducting, and only D2 conducting. Find the currents through the diodes and the voltages across them in all four cases.

If you assumed that a diode was conducting and you find that a positive current is in fact flowing through it, and if you assumed that a diode was non-conducting and you find that the voltage across it is negative (or less than \$V_f\$), then your assumption is correct. If you analyze a particular case and find that the voltages or currents are inconsistent with the assumptions then you can reject that case.

Once you find the only set of assumptions that is consistent with your analysis, you can go ahead and find \$V_{out}\$.

Comment: Ooh..Thank you!!!

Comment: @ripmsn Works for transistor modes of operation too